# Não ocultar div ao executar função

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

Olá, estou fazendo um projeto da faculdade cujo tenho que utilizar web forms. Por padrão no meu projeto tenho uma div que esta como none por padrão no css, e dentro desta div se encontra um pequeno formulario, como segue o exemplo:

OBS: esqueci de mencionar que este formulario é aberto através de um botão, que utilizando javascript faz o mesmo mudar de display: none, para display: inline-block.

```
 <div class="x_panel" id="div1">
          <div class="x_title">
            <h2>Cerâmicas X <small>cadastro de produto</small></h2>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="x_content">
            <br/>
            <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask">

              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_prod_modelo" runat="server"  class="form-control has-feedback-left" Text="Modelo do produto"></asp:TextBox>
                <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_prod_quantidade" runat="server"  class="form-control has-feedback-left" Text="Quantidade de produto"></asp:TextBox>   
                <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </div>
                <asp:Label ID="msg" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label>

               <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Onclick="Cadastrarproduto_Click"  />

          </form>
          </div>

   </div>
```

Pois bem, ao eu clickar no button, ele executa o metodo Cadastrarproduto através do onclick, e este onclick da um reload na pagina, fazendo com que o formulario volte a ser none. Ja tentei criar uma função javascript e colocar dentro do button em um OnclientClick mas também não deu certo. Não sei se consegui me expressar muito bem, mas gostaria de ajuda para que ou esse reload não ocorra ou para conseguir exibir novamente a minha div. Obrigado pela atenção e pela ajuda.

Comment: Tu tá dizendo que quando clica no Button1, pra cadastrar o produto, ele tá dando reload na página e tu gostaria que não fizesse isso? Que cadastrasse o produto e permanecesse com o form aberto?

Comment: exatamente! quando o Onclick é executado a pagina da um auto-reload e a div volta pra none

Comment: Tu já tentou fazer o cadastro por Ajax, por exemplo? Senão, tu poderia enviar algum parâmetro do code behind pro webform e verificar pra mostrar ou não...

Comment: Com o OnClientClick não deu certo pq?

Comment: Vou tentar realizar por ajax, pesquisei algumas perguntas semelhantes e recomendaram o mesmo. Vou dar uma pesquisada melhor aqui. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema, eu resolvi do seguinte modo:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm">
                </asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:updatepanel runat="server">
                 <ContentTemplate>

                //conteudo a ser controlado aqui.

                </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:updatepanel>
```